# React: props variable in url not collecting data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this, react-props

Quite new to react, I'm facing an unexpected behavior.
I'm trying to take data from a variable called a digest and assign it to newsId and send it to the node then python using ports. Below is the code where digest is defined in react.

```
 import './NewsPanel.css';
    import _ from 'lodash';
    import React from 'react';
    import Auth from '../Auth/Auth';
    import NewsCard from '../NewsCard/NewsCard';
    
    class NewsPanel extends React.Component{
       constructor() {
         super();
         this.state = {news: null, pageNum: 1, totalPages: 1, loadedAll: false};
         this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this);
       }
    
       componentDidMount() {
         this.loadMoreNews();
         this.loadMoreNews = _.debounce(this.loadMoreNews, 1000);
         window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
       }
    
       handleScroll() {
         let scrollY = window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
         if ((window.innerHeight + scrollY) >= (document.body.OffsetHeight - 50)) {
           console.log('Loading more news');
           this.loadMoreNews();
         }
       }
    
       loadMoreNews() {
         if (this.state.loadedAll === true) {
             return;
         }
         let url = `http://localhost:3000/news/userId/${Auth.getEmail()}/pageNum/${this.state.pageNum}`;
         let request = new Request(encodeURI(url), {
           method: 'GET',
           headers: {
               'Authorization': 'bearer ' + Auth.getToken()
           },
           cache: 'no-store'
         });
    
         fetch(request)
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(news => {
            if (!news || news.length === 0) {
                this.setState({loadedAll: true});
            }
            this.setState({
              news: this.state.news? this.state.news.concat(news) : news,
              pageNum: this.state.pageNum + 1
           });
       });
       }
    
       renderNews() {
         const news_list = this.state.news.map((news) => {
           return(
             <a className='list-group-item' key={news.digest} href='#' target='_blank'>
              <NewsCard news={news} />
            </a>
          );
        });
    
          return (
            <div className='container-fluid'>
              <div className='list-group'>
                {news_list}
              </div>
            </div>
          );
       }
    
       render() {
         if (this.state.news) {
           return(
             <div>
              {this.renderNews()}
             </div>
           );
         } else {
           return(
             <div>
              <div id='msg-app-loading'>
                Loading
              </div>
             </div>
           );
         }
       }
    
     }
    
    export default NewsPanel;
```

Below is the file when the variable is being called in url at newsId "sendClickLog()".

```
import './NewsCard.css';
import React from 'react';
import Auth from '../Auth/Auth';

class NewsCard extends React.Component{
    redirectToUrl(url) {
    this.sendClickLog();
    window.open(url, '_blank');
  }




 sendClickLog() {
           let url = `http://localhost:3000/news/userId/${Auth.getEmail()}/newsId/${this.props.news.digest}`;
            let request = new Request(encodeURI(url), {
              method: 'POST',
              headers: {'Authorization': 'bearer ' + Auth.getToken()},
              cache: 'no-store'
            });
            fetch(request);
      }
 

     render() {
 return(
      <div className='news-container' onClick={() => this.redirectToUrl(this.props.news.url)}>
        <div className='row'>
          <div className='col s4 fill'>
            <img src={this.props.news.urlToImage} alt='news' />
          </div>
          <div className='col s8'>
            <div className='news-intro-col'>
              <div className='new-intro-panel'>
                <h4>{this.props.news.title}</h4>
                <div className='news-description'>
                  <p>{this.props.news.description}</p>
                      <div>
                        {this.props.news.source.id != null && <div className='chip light-blue news-chip'>{this.props.news.source.name}</div>}
                        {this.props.news.reason != null && <div className='chip light-green news-chip'>{this.props.news.reason}</div>}
                        {this.props.news.time != null && <div className='chip amber news-chip'>{this.props.news.time}</div>}
                        {this.props.news.digest != null && <div className='chip amber news-chip'>{this.props.news.digest}</div>}
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    
        );
      }
    }
    export default NewsCard;
```

I thought the digest was empty and tested it using the web below is the result.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpXrP.png

Now below is the results when I try to assign and pass to python what it shows.
[Digest None](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srloF.png)

Can help me by check what is wrong with my code.

Comment: Can you check if `this.props.news.digest` is available inside your `NewsCard` component? Will it be possible for you to post the entire code?

Comment: @RohitKashap I have edited and put the whole code for the files affected above.